# What does dialogue from “Prison Break” “you look like you could use a few sharp edges knocked off your world” mean?

Tags: meaning

In prison break Season5 Episode2,after being beaten up by prison officers, Michael Scofield was returned to his cell. He looked at his Korean cellmate(being in withdrawal) and said “ you look like you could use a few sharp edges knocked off your world.”And the Korean guy said “you don’t look so good yourself.”

I figure Michael must’ve  meant “you look in bad shape.”But what does “knocked off”mean here? And how does “knocked off”define “a few sharp edges”?

Comment: It's a clumsy non-idiomatic construction that looks more like a "mixed metaphor" than anything else. We sometimes refer to a *person* having their metaphorical "sharp edges" knocked off / smoothed away (by harsh experience, etc.) where "sharp edges" is evocative of having "a chip on one's shoulder" (resentful, aggressive) or being "rough" (uncultured, ill-mannered). But it doesn't work well when those sharp edges are transferred to the addressee's *world* (which then apparently stands in as a synecdoche for the addressee himself).